# Retornar área de um triângulo usando função,gostaria de sugestões

Tags: python-3.x

```
   def main():  
       base = input("digite o valor da base do triangulo: ")
       altura = input("digite o valor da altura do triangulo: ")
       area = ((base*altura)/2)
     return area
main()
```

Comment: Seria interessante descrever melhor sua pergunta, assim você deixa a pergunta mais fácil de ser entendida e mais pessoas podem responder a sua pergunta

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar uma função que retorne o calculo da área e depois pode printar a função

```
def calcularArea(base, altura):
    area = ((base * altura) / 2)

    return area   

def main():  
    base = int(input("digite o valor da base do triangulo: "))
    altura = int(input("digite o valor da altura do triangulo: "))

    print(calcularArea(base, altura))

main()
```

Comment: tentei fazer desse jeito mas está retornando erro

Comment: Esqueci de fazer a conversão para inteiros no input, editei a resposta com a correção

Comment: O input, por padrão, só aceita string, caso queira usar int ou float deve fazer a conversão de tipos no input